# Maintain scroll position when switching between bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollbar

I have Bootstrap tabs that switch between panes which are using the [Malihu custom content scrollbar plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to override the browser scrollbars. However, when you click the different tabs, the scroll position is not maintained from the previous time you viewed the tab. The pane's scroll position returns to the top. Is there something I can do to maintain the scroll position?

I've created a fiddle to illustrate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/zfh3u37k/3/

```js
var container1 = $('.tab-body');

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  container1.append("<p>" + i + "</p>");
}

$(".tab-body").mCustomScrollbar({
  theme: 'minimal-dark',
  alwaysShowScrollbar: 0,
  autoHideScrollbar: true,
  advanced: {
    updateOnContentResize: true
  },
  mouseWheel: {
    scrollAmount: 150
  },
  scrollInertia: 350
});
```

```css
.tab-body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.0.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.0.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="tab-body">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="tab-body">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="tab-body">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check following solution, it works and supports each tab separately:

```
$(".tab-body").mCustomScrollbar({
  theme: 'minimal-dark',
  alwaysShowScrollbar: 0,
  autoHideScrollbar: true,
  advanced: {
    updateOnContentResize: true
  },
  mouseWheel: {
    scrollAmount: 150
  },
  scrollInertia: 350,
  callbacks: {
    onScroll: function() {
        var closestTabId = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
      $('[data-toggle="tab"][href="#'+closestTabId+'"]').data('scrolled', $(this).find('.mCSB_container').css('top'));
    }
  }
})

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {

   console.log($(e.target).data());

  $('.tab-pane.active'+$(e.target).attr('href')+' .mCSB_container').css('top', $(e.target).data('scrolled'));
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zfh3u37k/30/)

Comment: This is very close to being my accepted answer, however, my instance has multiple tab groups, with multiple tabs containing the class .tab-pane.active, and your solution causes all of the active panes to scroll, rather than just the one that the user is selecting. I've updated the fiddle here to show the multiple tab groups and the behavior I'm describing: http://jsfiddle.net/zfh3u37k/28/

Is there a way to modify your solution to fix this?

Comment: @skiindude22 I've updated the fiddle for multiple tab solution. Please check

Answer (score 2):

Use the below CSS to maintain the scroll positions like

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.tab-content>.active {
  display: block;
  width: initial;
  height: initial;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zfh3u37k/10/)

Comment: It doesn't work, the other tabs get scrolled to the same scrollY position.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following logic if all tabs content have same size (equal number of `<p>` elements).

Get scroll position once tab content is scrolled:

```
callbacks: {
    onScroll: function() {
      $(document).data('scrolled', $(this).find('.mCSB_container').css('top'));
    }
  }
```

Set it when needed using relevant bootstrap tab event:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  $('.tab-pane.active .mCSB_container').css('top', $(document).data('scrolled'));
});
```

[-=Updated jsFiddle=-](http://jsfiddle.net/zfh3u37k/4/)

Comment: The content and amounts of content in each panel is different, and the scroll positions will be different as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below solution. It's work on Here http://jsfiddle.net/zfh3u37k/9/

```js
var container1 = $('.tab-body');

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    container1.append("<p>"+i+"</p>");
}

$(".tab-body").mCustomScrollbar({
  theme: 'minimal-dark',
  alwaysShowScrollbar: 0,
  autoHideScrollbar: true,
  advanced:{ updateOnContentResize: true },
  mouseWheel:{ scrollAmount:150 },
  scrollInertia:350,
  callbacks: {
    onScroll: function() {
    vartabId='#'+$(this).find('.mCSB_container').parents('.tab-pane').attr('id');
    if ((vartabId == '#home')) {
        sessionStorage.homeScroll = $(this).find('.mCSB_container').css('top');
    } else if ((vartabId == '#menu1'))  {
        sessionStorage.menu1Scroll = $(this).find('.mCSB_container').css('top');
    }
    else if ((vartabId == '#menu2'))  {
        sessionStorage.menu2Scroll = $(this).find('.mCSB_container').css('top');
    }
    }
    }
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if ((target == '#home')) {
        $('.tab-pane.active .mCSB_container').css('top', sessionStorage.homeScroll);
    } else if ((target == '#menu1'))  {
        $('.tab-pane.active .mCSB_container').css('top', sessionStorage.menu1Scroll);
    }
    else if ((target == '#menu2'))  {
       $('.tab-pane.active .mCSB_container').css('top', sessionStorage.menu2Scroll);
    }
});
```

```css
.tab-body {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid black;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/3.0.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/3.0.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="tab-body">
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="tab-body">
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="tab-body">
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! While it does perform the requested functionality, I had to give Meghdad Hadidi the accepted answer, due to his solution not being tied to specific ID's.